# Can't make WebSocketBundle subscribe/publish works. I followed official tutorial, bad setup?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, websocket, yaml

I'm working on a **Symfony2** application with **WebSocketBundle**.
https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle.
The installation of the bundle has been done successfully.
So, I run a websocket server (port 8080 in local) with simple command : "php app/console gos:websocket:server" 
while my symfony server is running (port 8000 in local).

I setup a simple client javascript to use WebSocketBundle following official tutorial which is on the github of the bundle.

When I come to a page on my website, I am correctly connected to the websocket server.
**The problem comes when I want to use functions subscribe() and publish()** that allow a user to subscribe to a channel, when anybody publish something on this channel, the message is received by the subscriber.

**In my case, the message is not sent or received**, I don't really know why because no revelant error is shown, I tried to follow as accurately as possible the official tutorial here :
https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/TopicSetup.md
But, unfortunately, I can't manage to make this works. That's why I solicit you to help me.

I share you below the most revelant piece of code to show how the setup takes place :

*Client JavaScript :

[/web/js/own_scripts/gws_lobby.js]*

```
var webSocket = WS.connect("ws://127.0.0.1:8080");

webSocket.on("socket/connect", function(session){
  //session is an Autobahn JS WAMP session.
  console.log("Successfully Connected!"); // I see this message

  session.subscribe("dcqtv/lobby/1", function(uri, payload){
      console.log("Message reçu : "+payload.msg);
  });

  session.publish("dcqtv/lobby/1", "testpublish");
});

// I should see "Message reçu : testpublish" in the console but that not happen
```

*Parts of Topic Handler Service (only showing differences with this given in tutorial) :

[/src/AppBundle/DcqtvTopic.php]*

```
  namespace AppBundle;
  class DcqtvTopic implements TopicInterface {
    ...
    public function getName(){
        return 'dcqtv.topic';
    }
  }
```

*Register of the service with Symfony :

[/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml]*

```
services:
    dcqtv.topic:
        class: AppBundle\DcqtvTopic
        tags:
            - { name: gos_web_socket.topic }
```

*Link channel & topic with pubsub router (2 files here) :

[/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml]*

```
dcqtv_topic:
    channel: dcqtv/lobby/{lobby_id}
    handler:
        callback: 'dcqtv.topic' #related to the getName() of your topic
    requirements:
        lobby_id:
            pattern: "\d+"
```

*[/app/config/config.yml]*

```
gos_web_socket:
    server:
        port: 8080        #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: 127.0.0.1   #The host ip to bind to
        router:
          resources:
            - @AppBundle/Resources/config/pubsub/routing.yml
```

---

This is quite long because I want to be explicit and clear enough, there are much code but that is necessary to well understand the whole thing.

Feel free to ask questions.
Thanks for your attention. Sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loooks like you are missing

```
{{ ws_client() }}
```

https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/ClientSetup.md

Comment: That is the thing I forgot... How silly of me ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

hi i write this post to give you another way to use websocket and symfony i have never use your aproche but i build many application using this tutorial 
if you find yourself stuck you can use it [her](http://devblog.lexik.fr/symfony2/notifications-via-websocket-avec-symfony2-et-node-js-2679)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am too far in my project to change now but I will try out your solution in my future project.